# Using factories with events on rootScope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use my factory's fields in a rootScope event, but it doesn't seem to work :

```
ngModule.factory('MyFact', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        function MyFact(opts) {
            this.blah= opts.blah;
        }
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
            alert('This is my directive listening stateChangeStart' + this.blah);
        });

        return MyFact;
    }]);
```

What is displayed is : 'This is my directive listening stateChangeStartundefined'.

Why can't I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`this.blah` is out of scope.

It cant be seen by the `this.blah` in the `$rootScope.$on` make it available at a greater scope so it can be seen by your function.

Comment: I kind of get that, but I am still not sure how to make it available in rootScope's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a private `var` to be able to access it in the `$rootScope.$on function` since it is out of context:

```
ngModule.factory('MyFact', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var _blah;

    function MyFact(opts) {
        _blah= opts.blah;
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
        alert('This is my directive listening stateChangeStart' + _blah);
    });

    return MyFact;
}]);
```